# Iterating an IAsyncEnumerable in a function returning an IAsyncEnumerable with cancellation

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-8.0, ef-core-3.0, iasyncenumerable

As the title says, I have to following function:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Job> GetByPipeline(int pipelineId,
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    await foreach (var job in context.Jobs.Where(job => job.Pipeline.Id == pipelineId)
        .AsAsyncEnumerable()
        .WithCancellation(cancellationToken)
        .ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        yield return job;
    }
}
```

I have trouble wrapping my head around where the cancellation token is going, and a nagging feeling that I am using it in too many places.

What is actually happening here when you deconstruct all the fancy async stuff? And are there any better ways to write this function?

Comment: `AsAsyncEnumerable()` already returns an `IAsyncEnumerable<Job>`. You don't need the rest of the code, just return that, ie `return context.Jobs.Where(job => job.Pipeline.Id == pipelineId)
        .AsAsyncEnumerable()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It doesn't support a `CancellationToken` though, and the result of `WithCancellation` is not convertable to `IAsyncEnumerable`

Comment: Those calls only make sense on the *caller's* site. You'll have to add them *again* when you try to iterate over the IAsyncEnumerable

Comment: Besides, in this case, neither has much of an effect. You can't cancel the query even if you cancel the iteration, while `ConfigureAwait(false)` passes the decision of where to resume execution to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this method could be reduced to :

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<Job> GetByPipeline(int pipelineId)
{
    return context.Jobs
                  .Where(job => job.Pipeline.Id == pipelineId)
                  .AsAsyncEnumerable();
}
```

or even

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<Job> GetByPipeline(int pipelineId)
    => context.Jobs
              .Where(job => job.Pipeline.Id == pipelineId)
              .AsAsyncEnumerable();
```

The method doesn't do anything with `job` so it doesn't need to iterate over it.

**Cancellation**

What if the method actually used `job`, where should the cancellation token be used?

Let's clean up the method a bit. The equivalent is:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Job> GetByPipeline(
      int pipelineId, 
      [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    //Just a query, doesn't execute anything
    var query =context.Jobs.Where(job => job.Pipeline.Id == pipelineId);

    //Executes the query and returns the *results* as soon as they arrive in an async stream
    var jobStream=query.AsAsyncEnumerable();

    //Process the results from the async stream as they arrive
    await foreach (var job in jobStream.WithCancellation(ct).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        //Does *that* need cancelling?
        DoSometingExpensive(job);
    }
}
```

The IQueryable `query` doesn't run anything, it represents the query. It doesn't need cancellation.

`AsAsyncEnumerable()`, `AsEnumerable()`, `ToList()` etc *execute* the query and return some result. `ToList()` etc consume all the results while the `As...Enumerable()` methods produce results only when requested. The query can't be cancelled, the `As_Enumerable()` methods won't return anything unless asked for it, so they don't need cancellation.

`await foreach` will iterate over the entire async stream so if we want to be able to abort it, we *do* need to pass the cancellation token.

Finally, does `DoSometingExpensive(job);` need cancellation? Is it so expensive that we want to be able to break out of it if it takes too long? Or can we wait until it's finished before exiting the loop? If it needs cancellation, it will need the CancellationToken too.

**ConfigureAwait**

Finally, `ConfigureAwait(false)` isn't involved in cancellation, and may not be needed at all. Without it, after each `await` execution returns to the original synchronization context. In a desktop application, this meant the UI thread. That's what allows us to modify the UI in an async event handler.

If `GetByPipeline` runs on a desktop app and wanted to modify the UI, it would have to remove `ConfugureAwait` :

```
await foreach (var job in jobStream.WithCancellation(ct))
{
        //Update the UI
        toolStripProgressBar.Increment(1);
        toolStripStatusLabel.Text=job.Name;
        //Do the actual job
        DoSometingExpensive(job);
}
```

With `ConfigureAwait(false)`, execution continues on a threadpool thread and we *can't* touch the UI.

Library code shouldn't affect how execution resumes, so most libraries use `ConfigureAwait(false)` and leave the final decision to the UI developer.

If `GetByPipeline` is a library method, do use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that somewhere deep inside the Entity Framework is the method `GetJobs` that retrieves the `Job` objects form the database:

```
private static async IAsyncEnumerable<Job> GetJobs(DbDataReader dataReader,
    [EnumeratorCancellation]CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    while (await dataReader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken))
    {
        yield return new Job()
        {
            Id = (int)dataReader["Id"],
            Data = (byte[])dataReader["Data"]
        };
    }
}
```

Now imagine that the `Data` property contains a huge byte array with data accosiated with the `Job`. Retrieving the array of each `Job` may take some non-trivial amount of time. In this case breaking the loop **between** iterations would not be enough, because there would be a noticable delay between invoking the `Cancel` method and the raising of the `OperationCanceledException`. This is why the method [`DbDataReader.ReadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader.readasync) needs a `CancellationToken`, so that the query can be canceled instantly.

The challenge now is how to pass the `CancellationToken` passed by the client code to the `GetJobs` method, when a property like `context.Jobs` is along the way. The solution is the [`WithCancellation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskasyncenumerableextensions.withcancellation) extension method, that stores the token and passes it deeper, to a method accepting an argument decorated with the [`EnumeratorCancellation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.enumeratorcancellationattribute) attribute.

So in your case you have done everything correctly. You have included a `cancellationToken` argument in your `IAsyncEnumerable` returning method, which is the recommended practice. This way subsequent `WithCancellation` chained to your `GetByPipeline` method will not be wasted. Then you chained the `WithCancellation` after the [`AsAsyncEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.asasyncenumerable) inside your method, which is also correct. Otherwise the `CancellationToken` would not reach its final destination, the `GetJobs` method.