# What is the correct way to pass a cancellation token to an async stream?

Tags: c#, async-await, cancellation, .net-5, iasyncenumerable

For a while I've been trying to get my head around the whole async/await model that C# uses for asynchronous code. The addition of async streams (the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` type) seemed really cool, especially for some code that I was writing.

Best practice when creating an async method is to include a `CancellationToken` parameter and use it for cancelling your async processes. (Ideally by passing it to the underlying async method calls used in your method.)

When creating a method that returns an async stream (an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`) the documentation states that your `CancellationToken` parameter should be decorated with the `[EnumeratorCancellation]` attribute and then the token passed using the `.WithCancellation()` method on the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` itself.

However, I must be doing something wrong because this still triggers warning:

> CA2016: Forward the CancellationToken parameter to methods that take one

This warning appears regardless of if I do it the more standard way:

```csharp
async IAsyncEnumerable<aThingo> GetFlibbityStream([EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
    aThingo slowValue = null;
    do {
        aThingo slowValue = await GetThatThingo(cancellationToken);
        yield return slowValue;
    while (slowValue != null);
}


async Task DoingStuff(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    await foreach(var thng in ThingStreamCreator.GetFlibbityStream().WithCancellation(cancellationToken)) {
        CrushThatThing(thng);
    }
}
```

Or at points where I need to get the `AsyncEnumerator` itself (because I need to iterate through two async streams together, but not necessarily at the same rate.)

```csharp
async Task ValidatingThingsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    await using IAsyncEnumerator<aThingo> srcEnumerator = source.ThingValidityAsyncStream(dateCutOff).GetAsyncEnumerator(cancellationToken);
    ... streamy stuff ....
}
```

All of my async stream methods have a `default` value for the CancellationToken which makes them optional parameters. I think perhaps part of my problem is the `WithCancellation()` method is intended for use cases where you already have the `IAsyncStream<T>` but didn't necessarily pass the cancellation token to it. But that doesn't entirely make sense and it feels like I am either passing in the cancellation token too often or not enough (or doing the wrong one of those when I should be doing the other.)

Am I simply misusing `WithCancellation()` and `GetAsyncEnumerator()` by unnecessarily passing the cancellation token when I should simply be passing it to the async stream method directly in these cases?

Basically I should not be using `WithCancellation()` and I shouldn't be passing anything to `GetAsyncEnumerator()` and should instead remove the default value for the CancellationToken on my async stream methods and pass the token directly to them. Basically I think I'm confused by the number of different ways to pass a CancellationToken to an async stream and identifying which is the correct method to use at the time...

Comment: This seems like a bug. Are you using resharper perhaps ?

Comment: Nope, no ReSharper or anything. Just Visual Studio Enterprise edition. I did wonder if the warnings just haven't caught up with the new features yet.

Comment: Potentially you might want to clean your solution, or clear your bin and obj directories and restart. It seems the static analysis has a *bee in its bonnet* about something it shouldn't (at least in some of these cases).

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between returning AsyncEnumerable with EnumeratorCancellation or looping WithCancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59300561/whats-the-difference-between-returning-asyncenumerable-with-enumeratorcancellat) and also [Iterating an IAsyncEnumerable in a function returning an IAsyncEnumerable with cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58757843/iterating-an-iasyncenumerable-in-a-function-returning-an-iasyncenumerable-with-c)

Comment: @MikeD. Stephen Cleary had made a really neat presentation about Async Streams. In his talk he has several demos about async stream cancellation. [Here you can find it](https://youtu.be/-Tq4wLyen7Q?t=2887)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/async-streams):

> There are two main consumption scenarios:
>
> 1. await foreach (var i in GetData(token)) ... where the consumer calls the async-iterator method,
> 2. await foreach (var i in givenIAsyncEnumerable.WithCancellation(token)) ... where the consumer deals with a given IAsyncEnumerable instance.

You're calling `GetFlibbityStream` method, so this is the case #1. You should pass `CancellationToken` directly to the method and *should not* chain `GetFlibbityStream` with `WithCancellation`. Otherwise rule analyzer for CA2016  will emit warning, and it will be right.

`WithCancellation` is intended for the case #2. For example, there is some library type with property or method, which returns `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` and *does not* allow to pass `CancellationToken` directly.

Like this one:

```
public interface IFlibbityService
{
    IAsyncEnumerable<aThingo> FlibbityStream { get; }
}
```

This still supports cancellation, but the only way to pass token to `IFlibbityService.FlibbityStream` is to use `WithCancellation`:

```
await foreach(var thng in flibbityService.FlibbityStream.WithCancellation(cancellationToken))
{
    // ...
}
```

Back to your code, just throw away `WithCancellation` and pass token directly:

```
await foreach(var thng in ThingStreamCreator.GetFlibbityStream(cancellationToken))
{
}
```